# Transfering file from GWT client using FileUpload via RestyGWT

Tags: java, file-upload, gwt

i have a gwt client and now i am trying to transfer user's file(image) to server and save it them. Could you explain me how to transfer file from GWT using FileUpload via RestyGWT. I've found that is nessesary to use FormPanel, i think that i must to use setAction() and submit() method, but i am using RestyGWT, and i can't understand how can i transfer data via restyGWT?

Client side:

```
private FormPanel fileUploadPanel;
private FileUpload fileUpload;
private void create() {
//Some code //
    fileUpload = new FileUpload();
    fileUploadPanel = new FormPanel();
    fileUploadPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
    fileUploadPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    fileUpload.setName("upload");
    fileUploadPanel.setAction("http://localhost:8080/api/events/upload");
    fileUploadPanel.add(fileUpload);
//Some code//
}


 @POST
 @Path("UPLOAD_PATH")
 void uploadImage(/*i don't know how what must be here */,
             MethodCallback callback);
```

Server side:

```
 @Path("/upload")
 @POST
 @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
 public void uploadImage(
        @FormDataParam("upload") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("upload") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    String uploadedFileLocation = "some_path" + fileDetail.getFileName();

    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Client

```
public UploadPanel()
{
   Div div = new Div();

   final FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
   formPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
   formPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
   formPanel.setAction("uploadFileServletUrl");
   formPanel.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler()
   {
      @Override
      public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event)
      {
         GWT.log("event.getResults = " + event.getResults());
      }
   });

   FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
   fileUpload.getElement().setAttribute("multiple", null);
   fileUpload.setName("abcupload");
   div.add(fileUpload);
   Hidden hidden = new Hidden("id", "8"); //just an example of how to pass a parameter
   div.add(hidden);

   Button butUpload = new Button("Upload");
   div.add(butUpload);
   butUpload.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
      {
          formPanel.submit();
      }
   });

   formPanel.add(div);
   this.initWidget(formPanel);
}
```

This will POST a standard multipart requert to the server. There you will just have to read the parts (in this example you will have an "id" part, and a "abcupload" part which will be the file).

I can't post any Java serverside code as I always use C# for serverside, but it is should be just the standard way of reading in a multipart POST request.